# What is the purpose of having recursive algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I thinking about what is the true purpose of having recursive algorithm.
We all know that recursive algorithm is compact and understandable in some manners. However, the biggest drawback of recursion is that the recursive algorithm requires a *huge amount* of system resources while running. That leads to a consequence that is recursive algorithm should only be run on a very "simple data" (I'm not sure if I'm using the right word).

E.g: while I wrote an algorithm to calculate number of Lattice Paths for a certain matrix using recursive algorithm. That algorithm works well with small matrix size, but when dealing with matrix size > 20, it takes forever for the computer to finish the task. So I have to rewrote my algorithm using normal approach.

**Could anyone explain for me the purpose of having recursive algorithm?** since it's not very effective on system resource usage, and could be completely rewritten by normal approach (I know it might be hard sometimes to rewrite a recursive algorithm).

Comment: "the recursive algorithm requires a huge amount of system resources while running." It does? IIRC, a properly optimized tail-recursive function takes up no more space than an ordinary while loop.

Comment: I suspect this is off-topic here, but here's my view: If the problem is recursive in nature then a recursive code solution should be the first approach. Then, if performance isn't good enough you can look into converting it to a non-recursive version.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)  or ask on http://programmers.stackexchange.com since SO focuses on practical problems.

Comment: So that is the tail-recursion, I think. Thank you ;)

Comment: @Kevin but in some programming languages that don't support IIRC, e.g Java. What would you do?

Comment: I would use recursive algorithms anyway. In any case, I don't agree with your assertion that recursion is "not very effective on system resource usage". So there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: @Kevin Humm, as I stated in my question. I'm having a trouble in solving a problem using recursive method. e.g: find number of Lattice Path for a matrix with size (n * n). That algorithm works well for n < 18, but take a lot of time to solve when n > 18.
And "not very effective on system resource usage" is what I has been taught at school ^^

Answer (score 3):

Actually, in this case one person's trash is another person's treasure. But to back up, let us consider your claims of "huge amound of system resources": ignoring issues of caching and pipelining, the resource that recursive algorithms use "invisibly" is system stack space for making recursive calls: the current instruction pointer is pushed on the stack as well as all parameters to the recursive function. Plus the variables local to the recursive procedure are created on the stack, though this is the case in any function, but the memory taken up by local variables is multiplied times the depth of recursion. Nonetheless, this does not necessarily amount to "huge."

The advantage of recursion approaches (besides those you mention) is the fact that... wait for it... you can use the system stack as another data structure.  Consider a recursive algorithm for exploring a binary tree: by passing the **node** parameter to the recursive function, you are in effect maintaning a data structure (namely, a stack) which you would need to maintain explicitly in a non-recursive approach, with the difference that in a recursive function you don't have to actually declare and maintain your stack explicitly. So the only additional "waste" of recources is whatever else you need in the stack frame, plus the size of the instruction pointer on the stack * depth of recursion. For a simple-to-understand algorithm that is made simpler by not having to declare an explicit data structure to store the node pointers, this is a small price to pay.

Keep in mind that for many recursive functions, the recursive approach does not involve actual recursion: if the recursive call is made as the last call in the recursive function and the result of the recursive call is returned by the calling function itself, then [tail call optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) (available on many compilers) will generate non-recursive code.

Comment: Very clear explanation, thanks
Just can't understand your "in this case one person's trash is another person's treasure"